# OpenRowSet Stored Procedure Returned Data Capture

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Situation: SQL Server 2008 query calling a stored procedure on Informix IDS 11.7

I need to capture all returned data from `N'SELECT *` in a variable using dynamic SQL (do not want in a temp table).

What works: data is returned fine from Informix, but I need it in a column name for a form.

What I've tried:

1. `N'SELECT @Credit = *` does not work as there is no column name from the Informix SP to refer to as in `N'SELECT @Credit = cx.SP_Credit`
2. Tried a linked server using `OpenQuery` but actually have more trouble with that -- can't get data from Informix returned.

Generic code:

```
DECLARE @parameter NVARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @Credit    NVARCHAR (32)

SET @parameter = N'@Credit NVARCHAR (32)  OUTPUT'

DECLARE @SQL_TEXT   NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQL_TEXT = N'Select * from OPENROWSET ( ''MSDASQL'' , ''DSN=Informix_DB'' , ''execute procedure an_informix_stored_procedure ("parameter1", "parameter2")'') as cx'

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQL_TEXT,
    @parameter,
    @Credit OUTPUT;

select @Credit as credit;
```

Results so far  (I want the "1-3" stored in the Credit column that is currently NULL):

[image]

Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @parameter NVARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @Credit    NVARCHAR (32)

SET @parameter = N'@CreditOut NVARCHAR (32)  OUTPUT'

DECLARE @SQL_TEXT   NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQL_TEXT = N'SET @CreditOut = (Select * from OPENROWSET ( ''MSDASQL'' , ''DSN=Informix_DB'' , ''execute procedure an_informix_stored_procedure ("parameter1", "parameter2")'') as cx)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQL_TEXT,
    @parameter,
    @CreditOut = @Credit OUTPUT;

select @Credit as credit;
```

Comment: Be aware that will fail if there is more than one column or more than one row returned. You're not actually returning a recordset you're returning a scalar in this case.

Comment: Good point. In fact, I do need to capture a record/result set now for a different Informix procedure.  I need some help figuring that out too.  Any tips?

Comment: (sorry, got interrupted and my 5 minutes expired when commenting above)    Good point @ElectricLlama. In fact, I do need to capture a Record/Result Set now for a different Informix procedure. Any tips?   Ultimately I need to create a view of a Stored Procedure that has the above code for a form that can only make SELECT calls.  Here's a link of what I'm trying to do: [link](http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/execute-stored-procedure-within-query).  I can get the example in the link to work great, but when I try to make a view of my Stored Procedure, I get errors having no Result Set.

Comment: Please ignore my above 2 comments. Since Views cannot accept parameters, I have to try a different solution.